# Why /proc/status and /proc/smaps RSS value is different?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory

If I sum up all Rss fields in /proc/smaps I never get the same result as 
VmRss field in /proc/status

Who knows why this happens? Which value is true RSS?

Example:

```
cat /proc/16004/smaps | grep -P 'Rss'
Rss:                 836 kB
Rss:                 892 kB
Rss:                  92 kB
Rss:                  32 kB
Rss:                 440 kB
Rss:                   0 kB
Rss:                 168 kB
Rss:                  16 kB
Rss:                   0 kB
Rss:                   4 kB
Rss:                   0 kB
```

Sum is: 2480 Kb

```
cat /proc/16004/status | grep -i VmRSS
VmRSS:      2384 kB
```

P.S. Process in this example is static linked executable. No shared libraries.

```
file ~/cm_f_regex 
....: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```